# how to flip android buttons

Tags: android, animation, button, viewflipper, flip

I wanna make a custom button in android extending buttons. When I will click on button, it will be flipped 180 degree and showed the back image of the buttons. That means the button will have two images. When it is clicked it will change with animation of rotation along y axis.

Any help are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `ScaleAnimation`, which will stretch the button to 0 px width and then stretch it back to 100 %. When the button hast the minimal width, the background and text should be changed, in order to show the back side.

Answer (score 0):

at first sorry for my poor En.
and after that...

**your layout --> flip.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff00546c"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:visibility="gone"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

you define your first and second side of your button or any view hear.

**add this part in your activity**

```
public void onButtonClick(View view)
{
    flipView();
}

private void flipView()
{
    View rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root);
    View viewFace = findViewById(R.id.front);
    View viewBack = findViewById(R.id.back);

    FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(viewFace , viewBack );

    if (viewFace.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
    {
        flipAnimation.reverse();
    }
    rootLayout.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
}
```

this part of code start the flip animation, and the last part ...

**FlipAnimation.java**

```
public class FlipAnimation extends Animation {
private Camera camera;

private View fromView;
private View toView;

private float centerX;
private float centerY;

private boolean forward = true;

public FlipAnimation(View fromView, View toView) {
    this.fromView = fromView;
    this.toView = toView;

    setDuration(700);
    setFillAfter(false);
    setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
}

public void reverse() {
    forward = false;
    View switchView = toView;
    toView = fromView;
    fromView = switchView;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    centerX = width / 2;
    centerY = height / 2;
    camera = new Camera();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
{
    final double radians = Math.PI * interpolatedTime;
    float degrees = (float) (180.0 * radians / Math.PI);

    if (interpolatedTime >= 0.5f) {
        degrees -= 180.f;
        fromView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (forward)
        degrees = -degrees; //determines direction of rotation when flip begins

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
    camera.save();
    camera.translate(0, 0, Math.abs(degrees)*2);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.rotateY(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();
    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

}
}
```

enjoy!

and one thing else, i found this code in stack before, but not found that answer to link. some one else wright this useful code.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/stormzhang/FlipLayout -- use this library. Its easy to use and for you.